# Update clientUserId without correction

Tags: docusignapi

I have envelopes that were not created by the API and so their recipients don't have the `clientUserId` set.

I would like to update the `clientUserId` of a recipient so I can redirect them to sign the envelope with the `createRecipientView` method.

The problem is when I make the update ([EnvelopeRecipients::update](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/update)) DocuSign issues a correction, and makes the envelope unavailable for the other recipients, sending out an email that they no longer can access the document.

How can I prevent this correction?

*Edit: As far as I can tell the correction only applies to the recipient whose `clientUserId` is updated. Is this correct? Is it not possible for the recipient to sign both from their email and from the embedded flow? I can suppress the email with the `suppressEmails` field for the given signer, but they still won't be able to open the document from their email anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the envelope is in "draft" (created) state - would should be able to do that.
If the envelope was already sent - it has to be corrected. That's a legal requirement. It was sent to some recipient and now you modify it (in any way) then it's technically a correction, you can't avoid this.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. The problem I was trying to solve is allowing embedded signing for recipients of already sent envelopes while not revoking their access to open the envelope from the email. This is not possible, right?

Comment: Not unless your integration sent the envelope to begin with and set the clientUserId yourself.